# Speed up IF/ELIF search over index in multiple lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, if-statement

Is there a faster way to run the following code: (checks if a value in the `df.index` is in multiple lists, and if so it appends a string to one list and the index to another list)

```
truth = []
t_ind = []
for ind in df.index.values:
    if ind in t4:
        truth.append('a')
        t_ind.append(ind)
    elif ind in t8:
        truth.append('b')
        t_ind.append(ind)
    elif ind in nk:
        truth.append('c')
        t_ind.append(ind)
    elif ind in mono:
        truth.append('d')
        t_ind.append(ind)
    elif ind in b:
        truth.append('e')
        t_ind.append(ind)
    else:
        truth.append('Other')
        t_ind.append(ind)
```

where `t4, t8, mono, nk` and `b` are seperate lists with index values (int)

Comment: If the lists are large, it would be better to make them sets, since membership checking is O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make one big "index" dict, instead to check keys in separate ones.
In my example I suggested that t4 or t8 is dits. if you have dicts `t4 = {'t4_1':'value_1', 't4_2': 'value_2'}` and `t8 = {'t8_1': 'value_1', 't8_2': 'value_2'}`. Here you don't mind about values. `if ind in t4` means that you check key `ind` in t4 dict.
`dict.from_keys(t4.keys(), 'a')` will make dict `{'t4_1':'a', 't4_2':'a'}'.`
dict.update()` just updates all keys in dict. here how you will make index of all keys with values you need.

In case t4 and t8 is lists or sets, yes it is enought `dict.from_keys(t4, 'a')`.

```py
    idx = {}
    idx.update(dict.fromkeys(t4.keys(), 'a'))
    idx.update(dict.fromkeys(t8.keys(), 'b'))
    idx.update(dict.fromkeys(nk.keys(), 'c'))
    idx.update(dict.fromkeys(mono.keys(), 'd'))
    idx.update(dict.fromkeys(b.keys(), 'e'))

    truth = [idx.get(ind, 'Other') for ind in df.index.values]
    t_ind = df.index.values
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean ```..(t4, 'a')) ``` instead of ```..(t4.keys(), 'a'))```

Comment: Answered in answer body. This is code with suggested that you have dicts. If you have lists or sets you can use just `..(t4, 'a'))`

Comment: also answer below trying to use pandas. probably if you working with pandas frames it should be hte way how you can make your conditional update on pandas

Comment: `df[df.index.isin(t4)] = 'a'; df[df.index.isin(t8)] = 'b'...`

Answer (score 1):

A `numpy` based solution. `np.in1d` returns all the matching positions between two iterables. We find this matching positions one by one through iterating over your segment of indices i.e. `t4`, `t8` etc. A cheap hack on RHS with `chr(97) = 'a'`

```py
# create a list with all the elements as 'Others' 
truth = np.repeat('Other', len(df))

# iterate over index groups and impute truth with the matching group
for i, idx_group in enumerate([t4, t8, mono, nk, b]):
    truth[np.where(np.in1d(df.index.values, idx_group))[0]] = chr(97+i)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Fair enough, shall edit once I am back at my desk. Thanks for the pointer.